# JavaMail No Login Method

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-mail, imap

I am trying to login to an email account. This is working fine in my local machine.
When it is uploaded to `weblogic server` and try running it. I am facing the issues.

Please kindly help!

The credentials are working.

**Code:**

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props);
mailSession.setDebug(true);
Store mailStore;
mailStore = mailSession.getStore("imap");
mailStore.connect("outlook.office365.com", 
                  "email_framework@cccis.onmicrosoft.com", "Workfl0w");
Folder inboxFolder = mailStore.getFolder("INBOX");
inboxFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

// retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
Message[] messages = inboxFolder.getMessages();
System.out.println("Total Messages in the Inbox ---" + messages.length);
```

**Exception:**

```
>OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [QwBZADQAUABSADEANABDAEEAMAAwADQAOAAuAG4AYQBtAHAAcgBkADEANAAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAdABsAG8AbwBrAC4AYwBvAG0A]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 LOGINDISABLED STARTTLS SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=yyy@xxx.onmicrosoft.com, password=<non-null>>
javax.mail.MessagingException: No login methods supported!;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.ProtocolException: No login methods supported!
```

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  Maybe you're using a very old version before the ssl.enable property was added?  Can you post the rest of the JavaMail debug output?

Comment: Here is the detailed exception

Comment: DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.1
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, In
c]
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [TQBXAEgAUABSADEANwBDAEEAMAAwADgANAAuAG4AYQBtAHAAcgBkADEAN
wAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAdABsAG8AbwBrAC4AYwBvAG0A]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 LOGINDISABLED STARTTLS SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERA
L+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
NO LOGIN Supported

Comment: JavaMail 1.4.1 is 10 years old and doesn't support that property.  Use the "imaps" protocol instead.  Better yet, upgrade to the [current version of JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).

Comment: Hey, Thanks!. It worked. In my pom.xml i used 1.5 where as when i deploy the same code in weblogic it failed reason being weblogic has comeup with 1.4 so i need to specify in weblogic.xml to pick mine. I modified the changes in weblogic.xml. It worked.